# Variable not in scope - cabal build error

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to compile hemotik (https://github.com/nh2/hemokit) using cabal on opensuse tumbleweed and get the following error:

```
Variable not in scope: (<>)
```

in different parts of the program code such as:

```
-- | Command line parser for EEG selection. See `EmotivArgs`.
emotivArgsParser :: Parser EmotivArgs
emotivArgsParser = EmotivArgs
  <$> option (eitherReader parseModel)
      ( long "model" <> metavar "MODEL"
        <> value Consumer
        <> help "Consumer or Developer model, Consumer by default" )
  <*> (optional . option (maybeReader makeSerialNumberFromString "Serial number of has invalid format"))
      ( long "serial" <> metavar "SERIALNUMBER"
        <> help "The serial to use. If no --from-file is given, this will select the device" )
  <*> (optional . strOption)
      ( long "from-file" <> metavar "PATH"
        <> help "The file path to read from (e.g. /dev/hidraw0 or myfile.dump)" )
  where
    maybeReader :: (String -> Maybe a) -> String -> ReadM a
    maybeReader mbFn msg = eitherReader (maybe (fail msg) pure . mbFn)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `import Data.Monoid`

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson since your answer resolved the question, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `(<>)` operator and other common ones are in `Data.Monoid` so just

```
import Data.Monoid
```